# Java "synchronized" keyword doesn't forbid other threads from changing class member's internal elements

Tags: java, multithreading, list, synchronized

I'm referring to JCP 4.4.2 and it has following sample code

```
@ThreadSafe
public class ImprovedList<T> implements List<T>{
    private final List<T> list;
    public ImprovedList(List<T> list){this.list=list;}
    public synchronized boolean putIfAbsent(T x){
        boolean contains = list.contains(x);
        if(contains){
            list.add(x);
        }
        return !contains;
    }
    @Override
    public synchronized void clear(){list.clear();}
}
```

The book said this ImprovedList is thread safe, but I have a question:

The input parameter of the constructor "list" is from outside. So, although `putIfAbsent()` is `synchronized` on `ImprovedList`, there is no guarantee the lock is put on the internal elements of `ImprovedList.list`. If another thread is changing/adding any type [T] element into this `list`, `ImprovedList.putIfAbsent` could result undetermined state, I guess.

Please kindly help to correct my understandings.

Comment: How would another thread access the private field? Other than through the synchronized method? (ok you might break it using reflection, but that will be out of scope)

Comment: Keep a reference of list when constructing it?

Comment: @RobAudenaerde it has the reference to the underlying list so another thread can use it directly. As I said the book took an assumption to guarantee thread-safety

Comment: Surely `if(contains)` should be `if(!contains)`?

Comment: …and could be simplified to `return !list.contains(x) && list.add(x);`

Comment: Re, "The input parameter of the constructor `list` is from outside." That is a weak design. The weakness is somewhat mitigated by the fact that they tell you how to use the class safely in its documentation (see CodeScale's answer, below.) But, a more satisfying design would make it _impossible_ to use the class in an un-safe way (e.g., it could make a private copy of the given `list`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes exactly, but if you look in the book, they took this assumption:

> ImprovedList assumes that once a list is passed to its constructor,
> the client will not use the underlying list directly again, accessing
> it only via ImprovedList

Based on this assumption the code is thread-safe.